# Vim colorschemes ONLY works in .vimrc

Tags: vim, colors

If I'm editing specifically `~/.vimrc` in vim `:colorscheme <some colorscheme>` will do exactly what it's suppose to do. Only schemes in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors` will work though and not say in any other folder such as `~/.vim/colors/` (it returns `Cannot find colorscheme '<some colorscheme>`).

If I'm editing any other file besides `~/.vimrc`, `:colorscheme <some colorscheme>` doesn't return any error but only changes the background color, the `~` that are at the start of each line, and IF I'm lucky will change the text from yellow monotone to blue monotone or something of the sort.

The `.vimrc` file is empty right now.

Answer (score 1):

That's because highlighting is off by default syntax. Try `:syntax on` and if vim fails to recognise filetype you can do it manually with `set filetype=<filetype>`, for example `set filetype=php`.
while getting full list of syntax highlighting filetypes is simple in gvim, for console version you have several [options](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/YatfwaP0jZ4/4G2eTAaeE-oJ):
    a) list the autocommands which identify them

```
        :au filetypedetect

These autocommands are set by $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim; one of them runs
$VIMRUNTIME/scripts.vim to try to identify files from their contents
when the name, path, etc. are not enough.

b) check which filetypes have scripts to handle them

(gvim) Syntax => Show filetypes in menu

which, however, lists only preinstalled filetypes, and not with the name
under which the 'filetype' or 'syntax' option knows them;

or else, for each of the directories listed in the 'runtimepath' option,
list (using ls on Unix or dir, possibly dir /w to save space, on Windows):

<directory>/ftplugin/*.vim
<directory>/indent/*.vim
<directory>/syntax/*.vim

Note that 'filetype' (as used by ftplugin and indent scripts) and
'syntax' (as used by syntax scripts) are separate options, which have
usually the same value but could be different.

In a "vanilla" install of Vim with no third-party scripts installed, the
only value of <directory> above pointing to an existing, nonempty
directory is your $VIMRUNTIME directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't ever to get the colorscheme to work in Guake or the regular terminal, but
after trying the terminal terminator it worked just fine.